# Scanner inputMismatch

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

This is my code (simplified).

```
public class A {

    int num;
    
    public void method () {
        
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        num = scanner.nextInt();
        
        switch (num) {      
        case 1:         
            System.out.println("Hello 1");
            scanner.close();
            break;          
        case 2:         
            System.out.println("Hello 2");
            scanner.close();
            break;      
        case 3:
            System.out.println("Hello 3");
            scanner.close();
            break;
            
        default:
            System.out.println("\nPlease try again.");
            method();
        }
    }
}
```

I want any non-integer input like Strings to also run the default case and sysout the "Please try again" instead of getting an inputMismatch error, but i have no idea how to do it.

Basically any input that is not a 1,2 or 3 should jump to the default case.

Comment: You can't read a string with nextInt. You'll need nextLine, for sure, then deal with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this through this code as you are taking user input as integer and if you will enter a string it will through inputMismatch error as the compiler is expecting integer but getting string or character input.

Now what you can do is take a string as the user input. Here the complete code for you:

```
public class A {

String num;

public void method () {
    
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    num = scanner.nextLine();
    
    switch (num) {
    
    case "1":
        
        System.out.println("Hello 1");
        scanner.close();
        break;
        
    case "2":
        
        System.out.println("Hello 2");
        scanner.close();
        break;
    
    case "3":

        System.out.println("Hello 3");
        scanner.close();
        break;
        
    default:

        System.out.println("\nPlease try again.");
        method();
}
}
}
```

This is what you want. It will work for every input.

Comment: Never close a `Scanner` for `System.in` because it also closes `System.in` and there is no way to open it again without restarting the JVM.

Comment: Also, try to post a well-formatted code. Your IDE can format the code on the click of a button or on pressing a combination of the defined keys.

Comment: Yes, I got your point, I was resolving his main issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use scanner.hasNextInt() to check if the input is an integer. If not, assign zero to num which then results in matching the default.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get strings by `num = scanner.nextInt();`. But, I have an idea.

```
value = scanner.nextLine();
//Now, check it is string or int
boolean numeric = true;

    try {
        Double num = Double.parseDouble(value);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        numeric = false;
    }

if(numeric){
   Integer.parseInt(value)
}else{
   //you can write value= value. Or, you can left it empty also. Or, you can remove else statement also.
}

switch (num) {      
    case 1:         
        System.out.println("Hello 1");
        scanner.close();
        break;          
    case 2:         
        System.out.println("Hello 2");
        scanner.close();
        break;      
    case 3:
        System.out.println("Hello 3");
        scanner.close();
        break;
    case "Hello":
        System.out.println("Hello 3");
        scanner.close();
        break;
        
    default:
        System.out.println("\nPlease try again.");
        method();
    }
```

[@Badal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13983584/badal-sherpa) is correct also. And, I did it with keeping `int` value. And, I don't remember is there any other way to check is it string or not. So, Sorry.